# Windows Batch start python script with pipe

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch script or scheduled task that can run this:

```
pythonw manage.py runserver >nul
```

This will run if I wrote it from a command prompt, and return me the prompt, but if I try to run it using a batch file or an scheduled task it will open a window and lock itself in that command.
The window I will close adding a final "exit" but it will be locked in the first command unless I kill the process in the task manager.

How can I do this? if it works in the normal cmd why don't work the same way when in a .bat or .cmd file?

Comment: I don't know python, but pythonw is a GUI program therefore has no access to the console that starts it. Therefore the `>nul` is meaningless. However your specific problem is something else - in a batch CMD waits for GUI programs to exit (interactively CMD only waits for console programs). See `start /?` for help on this (it explains starting programs with and without using `start` - new behaviour is from Windows 2000 compared with Windows NT4). You probably should be using `python`, however see `start /w` if you want to use the GUI python in a console it's not designed for.

Comment: The part with >nul is because manage.py is a django script that is not meant to run in this way and uses the stdout in every action you perform with the webserver it creates. This is a workaround to make the Django dev server start on startup w/o console and no log just to hardcore testing.

Comment: I meant `start` without the `/w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after testing more and more I found something that works. Sorry for making the Question without searching and testing more.

This is what has worked:

```
CMD /c start "" /B path\to\pythonw.exe path\to\manage.py runserver > nul ^& exit
```

Inside a .cmd file.
Executing the file starts the Django dev webserver properly and a scheduled task that runs that .cmd file also start the server.

Comment: What happens if you just use `start "" /B path\to\pythonw.exe path\to\manage.py runserver > nul`? The `/B` is required to force cmd.exe to set the `stdout` handle, but why would you need `cmd /c ... ^& exit`? pythonw.exe doesn't use the console, so there shouldn't be a problem; the batch should just continue and exit. `start "" /B pythonw.exe -c "import time;time.sleep(60)" >nul` works fine for me. And if I attach a debugger I can see that `@$peb->ProcessParameters->StandardOutput` is the `nul` device, while `StandardInput` and `StandardError` are unset as `NULL`.

Comment: Well, I don't really know why I need that, but what I know is that without it when I launched this it would open a command window and not close it unless I do it by hand. Also, de problem is because the way manage.py works